# Creating a HTML table using data from python lib

Tags: python, html

I want to display data from an xls file into an HTML table. I am using openpyxl to read data from xls file. I used HTML codes to create a table using HTML tags, but I am unable to put data inside the table using variables. I am able to print `sheet['A2']` and see the value from xls file. I have assigned this value to a variable `a2`. How can I print the value from this variable inside HTML. More specifically, how can I put the value of variable inside this tag: `<tr><td class="cell">{%sheet['A2']%}</td> <td class="cell">Cell 1.2</td></tr>`

```
   import smtplib
   import openpyxl
   from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText
   from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
   from email import encoders

   def py_mail(SUBJECT, BODY, TO, FROM):
    """With this function we send out our html email"""


   book = 
   openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\download\DAILY_PROJECT_REPORT20180420.xlsx')
   sheet = book.active

   a2 = sheet['A2']



     # Record the MIME type text/html.
      HTML_BODY = MIMEText(BODY, 'html')

     if __name__ == "__main__":
 """Executes if the script is run as main script (for testing purposes)"""

     email_content = """
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>html title</title>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
       }

      table, td, th {
      border: 1px solid black;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       border-spacing: 5px;
      }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>

    <table style="width:70%">
       <tr>
    <th> PREPAC </th>
    <th> TEAM_STATUS </th>
    <th> TOTAL </th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class="cell">{%sheet['A2']}%</td><td class="cell">Cell 1.2</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr><td class="cell">Cell 2.1</td><td class="cell"></td></tr>

    </table>

    </body>
    """

     py_mail("Test email subject", email_content, TO, FROM)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> html = """<td>{}</td>"""
>>> s1A2 = 10
>>> print(html.format(s1A2))
<td>10</td>
```

Or using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
>>> print(f"""<td>{s1A2}</td>""")
<td>10</td>
>>>
```

Or use named replacement fields in the format string with a dictionary

```
>>> data = {'s1A2':10}
>>> html = """<td>{s1A2:}</td>"""
>>> print(html.format(**data))
<td>10</td>
>>>
```

---

Your string:

```
s = """<tr><td class="cell">{%sheet['A2']}%</td><td class="cell">Cell 1.2</td>"""
```

If using Python version 3.6+ use an f-string:

```
print(f"""<tr><td class="cell">{sheet['A2']}%</td><td class="cell">Cell 1.2</td>"""
```

Or use traditional formatting;

```
print("""<tr><td class="cell">{}%</td><td class="cell">Cell 1.2</td>""".format(sheet['A2']))
```

Comment: hello, I tried your example, unfortunately, it is not working for me. could you kindly tell me how can I print(html.format(s1A2)) inside the variable email_content, i have tried multiple options, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: @ShubhajitChanda did you look at any of the documentation I linked to in my answer?